# java app cannot connect to remote MySQL db but can connect to local MySQL db

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Given two MySQL servers, one local, one remote.
Both have a database foobar containing a table bohica.
Local server has users 'myadmin'@'%' , 'myadmin'@'localhost' defined.
Remote server has users 'myadmin'@'%' , 'myadmin'@'localhost' and 'myadmin'@'my.domain.com' defined.

Privileges have been granted to all these users and privileges flushed.

Both servers are up.

From a command prompt window I can connect to both servers, ie

```
mysql --user=myadmin --password=mylocalpw
mysql --user=myadmin --password=myremotepw --host=my.domain.com
```

Both succeed, which proves that I can reach and log in to the remote server.

My java/maven/hibernate app has a context file

```
...
<bean id="databasePropertiesServerB"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<!--
  <property name="location"          value="classpath:databaseServerBlocal.properties" />
-->
  <property name="location"          value="classpath:databaseServerBliveadmin.properties" />
  <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="$dbServerB{" />
  <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceServerB"  class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="uniqueResourceName"    value="XADBMS_B" />
  <property name="xaDataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" />
  <property name="xaProperties">
      <props>
          <prop key="databaseName">foobar</prop>
          <prop key="user">$dbServerB{hibernate.connection.username}</prop>
          <prop key="password">$dbServerB{hibernate.connection.password}</prop>
      </props>
  </property>
  <property name="poolSize"><value>20</value></property>
  <property name="testQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
</bean> 

<bean id="emfB" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="packagesToScan"         value="com.mybiz.forms" />
  <property name="dataSource"             ref="dataSourceServerB" />
  <property name="jpaDialect"             ref="jpaHibernateDialect" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"       ref="jpaHibernateVendorAdapter" />
  <property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">$dbServerB{hibernate.dialect}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">$dbServerB{hibernate.connection.characterEncoding}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">$dbServerB{hibernate.connection.driver_class}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">$dbServerB{hibernate.connection.url}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">$dbServerB{hibernate.connection.release_mode}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">$dbServerB{hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">$dbServerB{hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">$dbServerB{hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">$dbServerB{hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">$dbServerB{hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">$dbServerB{hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">$dbServerB{hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">$dbServerB{hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.AtomikosJTATransactionFactory</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean> 
...
```

and properies files
databaseServerBliveadmin.properties

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://my.domain.com:3306/foobar
hibernate.connection.username=myadmin
hibernate.connection.password=myremotepw
hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
hibernate.c3p0.init_size=10
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=10
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=50
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=600
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

and databaseServerBlocaladmin.properties

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foobar
hibernate.connection.username=myadmin
hibernate.connection.password=mylocalpw
hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
hibernate.c3p0.init_size=10
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=10
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=50
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=600
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Now it gets weird.
When I adjust the "location" property value in the "databasePropertiesServerB" bean to use databaseServerBlocal.properties,
the app can connect to the local server and do its thing as expected.

BUT (and you knew there a BUT coming...)

When I adjust the "location" property value in the "databasePropertiesServerB" bean to use databaseServerBliveadmin.properties,I get the dreaded

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

errmsg. I can log in manually to the remote server which proves the username and password are correct.
I've been very careful to spell the username and password values correctly in the two .properties files - no trailing spaces, etc. So I'm stumped at this point. Any ideas?

TIA,

Still-learning Stev

Comment: I would avoid using % (wildcard) when creating DB user accounts. This allows any server to connect if they know the username/password. Also, I like to use a unique username per application to enhance security. Finally, never put a DB host in your public DNS. It should be kept internal and in your /etc/hosts file instead if you are using linux.

Comment: The error message appears to be using the other properties file. I would create a different user account and password and try reconnecting.

Comment: No, I can confirm that databaseServerBliveadmin.properties is being used when selected by temporarily changing the username to helloThere and sure enough that shows up in the error message.

Comment: You are using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create for databaseServerBliveadmin.properties file and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update for databaseServerBlocaladmin.properties file .I think this is the issue.Please check.

Comment: Ok. Tell me are you creating database from scratch in case of remote server? And try this also 
jdbc:mysql://my.domain.com:3306/foobar?user=myadmin&password=myremotepw   in your properties file.

Comment: Answer to first question : no, database is not being created from scratch, it already exists and is populated. And as for the second, even though these seem to be covered by lines 4/5/6 in databaseServerBliveadmin.properties, I will try it - stranger things have happened. Thx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

complete answer appears here in a subsequent question

[cannot achieve connectivity with MySQL db on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312680)

basically, everything about the hibernate properties file and the accounts and passwords on both instances of MySQL were all correct - the cause was not explicitly setting the xaProperties.server  property in the Atomikos datasource bean that gets used by the entity manager factory bean - if not explicity set it defaults to 'localhost', which of course doesn't work on a remote machine because there it's trying to log in as xxxxx.%

Sneaky sneaky sneaky.

CASE CLOSED

Still-learning Steve